# Is it good practice to call model methods inside other model methods in Django?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I'm trying to write my code as "Pythonic" as possible in Django.
Consider the following model:

```
class MyRequest(models.Model):
   ...

   def get_prices(self):
      ...

   def set_costs(self):
      ...

   def get_details(self):
       self.set_costs()
       x = self.get_prices()
       return x % 10
```

Is it good practice to call model methods inside each other?

Comment: What options come to your mind?

Comment: @IvanStarostin It looks ok to me. Maybe calling all required methods in the controller?
My main concern is calling methods inside each other may contradict with python's "Simple is better than complex" idea.